# Apple Map on Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, apple-maps

I know this would be a very easy trick but I am not able to find it anywhere. Could anyone please tell me how to Zoom out Apple Map on simulator? Please tell me mouse actions or touchpad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a pinch gesture just like on a real iOS device.

To simulate a pinch gesture, hold down the Option key on your keyboard. You will see two gray circles appear in the simulator. Move the two circles apart a bit then drag them toward each other to simulate the pinch.